# Power BI Running Total Revenue CM

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry2A5.png)
i am learning power bi and i am given a dashboard by my friend. So he asked me to make a dashboard like this however when try to get   Running total revenue cm ( i think it describes current month) i get totally different numbers
Running Total CM = CALCULATE([Total Revenue],FILTER(ALL('Date'),'Date'[Date]<=MAX('Date'[Date])))
i calculated it like this and by each month i got completely different numbers . And i can even understand the logic of this part and what it describes and what formula he used here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLaR1.png)

i would like to know what this exactly describes and how it is calculated so i can do the same

Comment: CM here = Cumulative Month, the clue is the middle table in the right. The numbers increase per month.